# Dynamic Survey Creation Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I want a user to create an event, on this event they need to be able to create a dynamic form form for the user to 'register' for the event (creating fields on the fly). Data which is then submitted to this form will get stored in the database. I've used most of [this tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/403-dynamic-forms) to get me to where I am now.

My structure looks like this so far:

```
class Admin::Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :body, :date, :title, :end_date, :status, :event_location_id, :payment, :fields_attributes, :answers

  belongs_to :event_location

  has_many :fields, class_name: "Admin::EventField"
  has_many :event_surveys
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :fields, allow_destroy: true

end
```

I have been able to successfully dynamically create fields against an event which get stored in admin_event_fields table. Done exactly how the Rails Cast tutorial does it.

```
class Admin::EventField < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  attr_accessible :field_type, :name, :required
end
```

I then have this model, my idea is to store the answers in a hash; so when one user submits a 'survey' it gets saved against the admin_event_id then the answers get stored in the answers hash. This should repeat when another user submits an answer... My Issue is, saving the answers to Admin::EventSurvey... I can't figure out a logical way to do this.

```
class Admin::EventSurvey < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :admin_event_id, :answers

  has_one :admin_event, :class_name => "Admin::Event"
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :admin_event, :allow_destroy => true

  serialize :answers, Hash
end
```

Because the form is going to be submitable from the show action, i've put a form in show.html.erb.

Admin::EventsController:

```
  # Admin::EventsController 

  # GET /events/1
  # GET /events/1.json
  def show
    @event = Admin::Event.find(params[:id])
    @event_survey_answer = Admin::EventSurvey.new(admin_event_id: params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @event }
    end
  end
```

Show.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for @event_survey_answer do |f| %>
<% if @event_survey_answer.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@event_survey_answer.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this event_survey_answer from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @event_survey_answer.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <% f.fields_for :admin_event do %>
    <%= @event.fields.each do |field| %>
        <%= render "admin/events/fields/#{field.field_type}", locals: { field: field, f: builder }  %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>


  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

At the moment with the above error I'm getting this error because of the loop on @event.fields:

```
undefined local variable or method `builder'
```

Comment: replace `builder` with `f`

Comment: @apneadiving now I get `undefined local variable or method 'f'` on the partial _text_field.html.erb

Comment: show the code of _text_field.html.erb

Comment: @SachinSingh 

`<div class="field">
  <%= f.label field.name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field field.name %>
</div>`

Comment: use this line

<%= render "admin/events/fields/#{field.field_type}", field: field, f: f  %>

instead of 

<%= render "admin/events/fields/#{field.field_type}", locals: { field: field, f: builder }  %>

Comment: @SachinSingh Thank you, now I'm getting `'undefined method 'name' for #<Admin::EventSurvey:0x47ab778>` which is odd, as it shouldn't be looking at `Admin::EventSurvey`, it should be looking at the association of `Admin::EventFields` on `Admin::Event`?

Comment: @SachinSingh I've modified the show.html.erb `fields_for :answers` to look at `:admin_event` instead, no erros - however I have no fields being displayed, just the submit button?

Comment: <% f.fields_for :admin_event do |ae_form| %> instead of <% f.fields_for :admin_event do %> and use it in rendering partial. Also put one of your partial to see what variable you use.